Unwanted space in tcbraster
I've run into undesirable behavior with tcolorbox that I cannot understand, and am hoping someone here can give insight into what's going on. If I compile the following (for me using pdflatex 2023) then there is unwanted spacing in the 3rd row.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
attach title to upper,%
before title={\hspace{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}},%
title={\notblank{#1}{}{}}%
}%

\begin{document}%

\begin{tcbraster}[%
raster left skip=0.05\linewidth%
]%
\begin{mybox}{1}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{2}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{3}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{4}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{5}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-45\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{6}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{7}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{8}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\end{tcbraster}%
\end{document}


This is a MWE so the code might seem strange, but I whittled down my real example to this. Any time the content of one of these boxes is just a bit too large, like the first box in the 3rd row, there is this extra indenting. Also there is a small amount of vertical space added there. You can see this here:

If I comment out any one of the three options to the \newtcolorbox, the unwanted space goes away. If I comment out the one option to the tcbraster environment, that also makes the unwanted space go away. So it seems that it's not any one of those options; it's all of them in combination.
Also I find this strange: if I replace title={\notblank{#1}{}{}} with title={} or title={{}}, that also makes the unwanted space go away. This suggests that \notblank{}{}{} does not work in the way I would expect.
Can anyone explain what introduces the extra space? Or how I can prevent this with global tcbsettings? (I know with this particular example I could change some of the widths that are used here, but in general I cannot predict the width of the content in each box and I am hoping to find a solution that is agnostic to the particulars of any width.)

Added later. Here is a less minimal example. The application produces a numbered list of math exercises. Some of them have titles. After bringing back some of the things I previously removed for the MWE, I have to make the troublesome 5th box a bit larger to trigger the issue. The 4th box with a faux title also now demonstrates the issue.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{
size=minimal,
boxrule=-0.3pt,
frame empty,
colback=white,
colbacktitle=white,
coltitle=black,
opacityfill=0.0,
fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries, attach title to upper,
before skip={1.5ex plus 0.5ex},
left=5ex,
halign=flush left,
unbreakable,
before title={\hspace{-5ex}\makebox[5ex][l]{#1.}},
title={\notblank{#2}{#2. }{}},
}


\begin{document}%
\begin{tcbraster}[%
raster left skip=0.05\linewidth%
]%
\begin{mybox}{1}{Title}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{2}{}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{3}{}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{4}{Title}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{5}{}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4567\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{6}{}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{7}{}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{8}{}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\end{tcbraster}%
\end{document}


@AndréC The 5th box is intentionally one character more wide that surrounding boxes. It has a "5" at the end. This makes it just long enough to trigger this issue.

It seems that if I remove the braces that surround all of my math expressions, that may resolve my issue (pending more testing).

you need before title={\hspace*{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}},%, to avoid that you loose the negative space sometimes.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks, I think this is the answer. Would you like to make it an answer that I can mark accepted?

you need
before title={\hspace*{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}},%

with a starred \hspace, to avoid that you lose the negative space in some cases.

I'm not sure what you're doing with titles, because \notblank{#1}{}{} will execute nothing at all.
Anyway, removing all unnecessary % and \left–\right commands, I get no issue. You can see that removing all % from your code has no influence on the output. I'm certainly not saying that they're not useful and sometimes necessary; they aren't in the cases you used them.
Also \left and \right in this context just produces unwanted space.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
  attach title to upper,
  before title={\hspace{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}},
  title={\notblank{#1}{}{}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[
  raster left skip=0.05\linewidth
]
\begin{mybox}{1}
\(1+2=3\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{2}
\(1+2=3\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{3}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-4)\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{4}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-4)\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{5}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-45)\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{6}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-4)\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{7}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-4)\)
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{8}
\(12(345-678)-90(123-4)\)
\end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}



"I'm not sure what you're doing with titles"... well I pared down a real example to an MWE because I thought it would be helpful. Should I post a larger example?

And removing the \left and \right just makes the expression narrower, because the extra spacing added by \left and \right is absent. I know I don't have the issue if the content is narrower.

I could have been more clear, but this is not tex that is manually edited, so I can't do some small local adjustment to get past this issue when it happens. I'm working on software that produces big tex files to be compiled so I'm looking for a global tcb adjustments to combat this.

I added a more complete example that might explain what is going on with titles.

Sorry for the comment barrage, but about "\notblank{#1}{}{} will execute nothing at all". I would agree with that, except that it's not equivalent to just having {} there. If I take my original example and only replace \notblank{#1}{}{} with {}, I get a different result. That is part of the mystery I can't solve.

@alex.jordan I see no difference.

That is odd then. I just confirmed that I do see a difference. Perhaps a difference in distributions? If I replace title={\notblank{#1}{}{}}% in the original example with title={}%, the unwanted space goes away. Meanwhile I commented on my post with a new observation. If I just remove the braces that surround my math expressions, that also clears this up. And that may be something I can control with the algorithmic production of these items.

Have a look to this solution:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
}%

\begin{document}%

\begin{tcbraster}[%
raster left skip=0.05\linewidth%
]%
\begin{mybox}{1}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{2}%
\(1+2=3\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{3}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{4}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{5}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-45\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{6}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{7}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\begin{mybox}{8}%
\({12\left(345-678\right)-90\left(123-4\right)}\)%
\end{mybox}%
\end{tcbraster}%
\end{document}

What generates the following:

What did I change?
I removed the following lines from the mybox definition:
attach title to upper,%
before title={\hspace{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}},%
title={\notblank{#1}{}{}}

These lines were responsible for adding a title to each box, which included the number in the top-left corner. By removing them, the title is no longer displayed, and the numbers are gone.
In particular:

attach title to upper was adding a title to the top of each box.
before title={\hspace{-5ex}\makebox[5ex]{#1.}} was adding a
horizontal space and a box with the number #1. before the title.
title={\notblank{#1}{}{}} was setting the title to be the number #1
if it was not blank, and empty otherwise.

By removing these lines, the title is no longer displayed, and the numbers are no longer shown.

I'm sorry, my attempt to make an MWE has misled people (both you and egreg) to think I am free to remove those frivolous lines. Those lines have more meaningful content in my real example and I cannot remove them. I just pared them down to eliminate their content as being relevant.
